# How to define a map view on map?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm new on the site (as a member). I'm developping an android map working with Google Maps APIv2. I want that when the map starts show the Iberian Peninsula and not elsewhere. I read that I can use the LatLngBounds.Builder class to do it. But someone can to explain me better how can i do it?

Regard

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you in working with Google maps api v2 on your app:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map?hl=en

You can default to a location by providing the lattitude and longitude of the location(in your case, lattitude and longitude of Iberian Peninsula). It can be done by the following code:

```
  LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(lattitude,longitude);           

  CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(currentLatLng)
                .zoom(MAP_ZOOM)
                .bearing(MAP_BEARING)
                .build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Provide the lattiude and longitude value in the 'lattitude' and 'longitude' variable respectively.

This link gives more details on it:
[view target location](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#target_location)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works perfectly. I hope to help you as you helped me.